# I need to write a program that reads a file which will output all unique integers, if the integer has been seen already it will be dismissed

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void read_file(fstream &file);

int main()
{
    fstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Data.txt");
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error with opening file";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        read_file(inFile);
    }

    inFile.close();

    return 0;
}

void read_file(fstream &file)
{
    int arr[100];
    fstream inFile;
    int number;
    int number_trash;
    int number_hold;

    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
        {
            inFile >> number;
            number_hold = number;
            if (number != number_hold)
            {
                arr[i] = number;
                cout << arr[i] << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                number_trash = number;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `file` != `inFile`.

Comment: for what part exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `read_file()` function, you're passing an `fstream` instance of an already open file, which is correct, however, later in the same function, you declare a new instance of `fstream` called `inFile` which is not open and you're trying to read from this file stream.

Remove the `fstream inFile` and read from the `file` which your function takes as an argument.

Also, your algorithm is not correct - the first if statement condition will be always evaluated to false. You're assigning `number` to `number_hold` and then you're checking for their non-equality.

As a solution, consider something like this:

```
void read_file(fstream &file)
{
    set<int> arr; // storage for your unique numbers
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        int number;
        file >> number; // read the number

        // check if this number is already in your unique list
        if (arr.find(number) == arr.end()) { // If it isn't, print it out...
            cout << number << endl;
            arr.insert(number); // ...and put it to your unique list
        }
    }
}
```

Note that for this to work you have to include another header file called `set`

```
#include <set>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. Is there a possible way that you could do this without using the #include<set>. As i have not learned that in class yet

Comment: Of course there is a way :-) What about [something like this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8c38f06bb446afa)?

Comment: wow thank you so much it works, had me scared at first cause of the first program.

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Please, don't forget to mark the answer as a solution.